# WARNING: The (sub)resource method contains empty path annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

I have configured rest path like "/v1/" and the endpoint configured in servlet like '/test/'.

Now I removed the "/v1" from the java class "Test".

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method test in com.abc.services.Test contains empty path annotation.
```

I got the above warning after make this change. How to handle this warning?

And I want this "/v1" removing changes for across 10 rest paths. So anyone help me to run without  warnings?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The warning means you have a resource method annotated with `@Path("/")` or `@Path("")`. For instance

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public String test(){}
}
```

Not sure why Jersey would give a warning, maybe just to make sure that's what you really want. The reason is that a resource method with `@Path("/")` is redundant, as it's already implied if you were just to do

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    public String test(){}
}
```

without the `@Path("/")`. It works the same. So if you have these, remove them, and it should take away the warnings.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillest. Its working now without warnings.

Comment: thanks. Does not apply to class level annotation though, "/" is required in that case.