# Wildfly with Basic Auth blocks requests with HTTP POST is not allowed for this method

Tags: rest, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy, wildfly-10

I have a strange problem which is not reproducible at the moment.
I have the following endpoints:

```
@Path("/v1/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EndpointVersion1Base
{
    private BackendRestClient restClient;


    @EJB
    public void setRestClient(BackendRestClient restClient)
    {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }


    @Path("/dataprivacy/")
    public Object getDataPrivacy()
    {
        return new DataPrivacyEndpoint(restClient);
    }

    @Path("/crashreporting/")
    public Object getCrashReport()
    {
        return new CrashReportEndpoint(restClient);
    }
}
```

The endpoint crashreporting has a Basic authentication. The endpoint dataprivacy has no authentication. The dataprivacy endpoint looks like this:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DataPrivacyEndpoint
{
    private BackendRestClient restClient;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public DataPrivacyEndpoint(BackendRestClient restClient)
    {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    public DataPrivacyEndpoint()
    {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeConsent(
            @NotNull(message = ErrorCodes.ERR_QUERY_PARAM_NULL) @Valid String consentInputBo) throws ForbiddenException, BadRequestException
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I achieved the Basic Auth of the crashreporting endpoint by the following web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>publicapi</display-name>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Crash reporting</web-resource-name>
            <description>crash reporting service</description>
            <url-pattern>/v1/crashreporting/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>publicapi</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>UserRoles simple realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>publicapi</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

and jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>publicapi</context-root>
    <security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Yesterday all this worked. Today I started the services. Suddenly, as I sent a POST request to the dataprivacy endpoint via **http://192.168.0.80:8080/publicapi/v1/dataprivacy/** and I got an HTTP error response "**HTTP POST is not allowed for this method**".
I wondered why this happened because it worked yesterday. After I restarted the services it suddenly worked again?!. What is going on here? Why does it sometimes work and sometimes not? (Currently I can't reproduce it). Do I have some misconfiguration in here which could lead to some strange behaviour? I'm afraid that this could happen on my LIVE system as well.

Comment: This is probably not the cause of the problem, but if `DataPrivacyEndpoint` is a sub-resource class, it should not be annotated with `@Path`. If it is, and you are classpath scanning for your resources, then it will be registered as a root resource class, which you don't want. also the `@Path("/")` on the method is redundant and is not needed; it is already implied. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520779/2587435).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks. I removed these parts and it is still working. I will proceed with this implementation and watch the behaviour.